# Is there software to automatically backup photos from Android device without going through a web service?

Tags: android, backup, images

Between my wife and I we have a multitude of smart phones and tablets, and all get used to varying degrees to take photos.

I'm looking for a Android App that will automatically backup photos to a directory of my choosing on my local network.

Here's a summary of what I'm looking for:

- Automatically backup the photos on any android device when connected to my home Wi-Fi
- Backup folder can be any folder I choose (which would be my home server)
- The Android App would ideally be compatible with Android 4.0, but most of the devices are using Android 4.3
- Any software on the destination would have to be compatible with Windows Server 2012 R2
- Preferably free  (gratis), although that is not set in stone if exactly what I want can be found.

I am aware that there are a number of services that will back the photos up automatically, but given these are usually services that backup photos to their cloud and/or required a Google + account (which I am desperately trying to avoid), they are not what I am looking for to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 4):

I use [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite) ([Pro/Full version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full)) to back to my NAS nightly. You can add many different 'accounts' (free version is limited to 2) including FTP, WebDAV or windows share (Samba/CIFS) but it also supports cloud services like Dropbox, OneDrive and Box.net.

You can specify whether to sync one way or two way and whether to sync deletions or not. You can also configure it to only attempt to sync when connected to particular wifi networks and also whether to only sync when charging.

You can specify which folder(s) on your device that you want to sync and in the full version you can also specify filters to only backup files that are a specific type or start/end with a specific value.

If you don't want to install/buy from Google Play you can see more information and other sites to get the app from (including directly from them) on [their website](http://www.tacit.dk/foldersync)

Comment: This looks promising.  I will investigate it when I get a chance

Answer (score 2):

[BitTorrent](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync) Sync can do what you want.

It syncs a folder between various devices/computers. Like Dropbox without a central server.

You can configure it only only sync when on Wi-Fi.

Download outside of Google Play: http://syncapp.bittorrent.com/1.3.87/ (or similar, first check what is the latest version)

Comment: i'll rather recommend [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/) which is a FOSS equivalent.

Comment: @DJCrashdummy: Sounds great please post a detailed answer about it :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [AndFTP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lysesoft.andftp) with [AndFTPpro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lysesoft.andftppro) to sync my photos and music.

Features:

- Automatic backup of files and directories over Wi-Fi. Customizable backup periods, and a home screen widget for manual backup with a single tap
- Ability to choose any folder on the server provided appropriate sharing permissions
- Compatible with Android 1.5 and higher
- Compatible with any FTP server on the destination. I use [Bitvise SFTP](http://www.bitvise.com/configuring-ssh-server-for-sftp)
- File transfer is free. Automatic sync is only in the paid version

Not exclusive for photos. It works on any directory

[image]

<sup>(click to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

There are some DIY cloud solutions that might work for you. For instance, OwnCloud's Android client claims they have [automatic photo upload](https://owncloud.com/products/mobileapps/) (I haven't used it myself).

It is a web service in the sense that you must maintain an OwnCloud server open to the internet, but it is a web service entirely under your control.

Alternatively, you could have the OwnCloud server only listen on your LAN, not the general internet. Then your phone's OwnCloud client will only connect to the server's IP when you're actually connected to it. You could use something like Tasker to prevent it from attempting to connect on networks that don't have the right SSID.