# Simple free tool to back up my SD card with my PC

Tags: windows, gratis, backup, file-synchronization, flashcard

So I have my Galaxy S4 with 64 GB SD card. Every once in a while I backup my SD card data simply by copy & paste it to a new directory in my PC.

So I have my `SD_BACKUP` root directory that contains sub directories of the entire SD card folder that was copied by the data.

```
C:/SD_BACK/BACKUP_30042014
C:/SD_BACK/BACKUP_27052014
C:/SD_BACK/BACKUP_15072014
```

and so on …

This is clearly not optimal. I am looking for a smarter tool:

1. Manage two storage folders: SD card on the device and `C:/SD_BACK`.
2. Smart copy of folder 'X' data into folder 'Y' (append and skip mode).
3. No syncing. `C:/SD_BACK` is always growing (nothing is removed by the tool). SD card is untouched.

So I tried two tools: [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155) & [FreeFileSync](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freefilesync/). Unfortunately as I see it, both tools are unable to sync **portable device** (I just can't chose my SD card folder from my device).

I know it is a very long question for a very simple and elementary task but I had to provide all I know and need.

### Update 1

Screenshot of FreeFileSync when I try to chose my SD card:

[image: FreeFileSync choose folder]

### Update 2

So it seem we narrow down the issue to **How to connect my device in *USB mass storage* mode?**

The post [Enable the USB Mass Storage for Samsung Galaxy S4](http://www.android.gs/enable-the-usb-mass-storage-for-samsung-galaxy-s4/) should help most users, but when I tried **step 5**:

> Tap on the ‘Mass Storage Mode’ button that’s shown on the main app menu

I got this error:

> Failed to turn on Mass Storage Mode, checkthat you have a microSD and that no apps are accessing it

Keep investigating [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2297888&page=5).

Comment: I have used FreeFileSync on an SD card before. Doesn't yours have a drive letter?

Comment: No. Just say `Galaxy S4` under `Portable Devices` category.

Comment: What is the displayed folder path when you open it with Windows Explorer? Maybe you can copy that into your sync program

Comment: Updated my question. please see screen shot.

Comment: Perahps this question is `how to make win 7 show SD card as a regular volume?`

Comment: That would be more relevant on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/), but I think you can mount it as a regular drive if you choose the ``USB mass storage`` option in the connection settings on your phone

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18222/discussion-between-idanshmu-and-timmy).

Comment: @idanshmu And after that, update your question with the answers you gave in comments. Especially the fact whether it has or does not have a drive letter (or whether you want it to) makes all the difference in available solutions.

Comment: Related: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3067/6834

Answer (score 2):

## [FTPServer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lutey.FTPServer) + [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/download.php)

Consider using an FTP server. You'd be able to backup your data wirelessly without having to figure out how to connect your device as a USB mass storage.

## On your phone:

1. Download and install [FTPServer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lutey.FTPServer)
2. Set up a username and password, choose any port number greater than 1023, and use **wlan0(IPv4)** as the *DEFAULT INTERFACE* and remember the IP address
3. Choose your home network in the *Allowed connections*
4. Select `/mnt/extSdCard` as the *Default Directory*
5. Go back and **Start FTP service**

[image: Click to enlarge]

## On your PC:

1. Download and install [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/download.php)
2. Select **FTP** from the *File Protocol* menu
3. Use your server's IP address, port, username, and password. Save your profile for later use
4. Log in and use the **Synchronize** button to back up your data
5. To match your criteria of one-way syncing without deletions, make sure that the **Local** option is selected and that **Delete files** is unchecked. You can also **Preview changes** before applying them

[image]
[image]