# Q: Sync files from PC to devices that are not exposed as a drive on Windows PC

Tags: file-synchronization, usb

I use perforce and/or synctoy for syncing files to my devices, such as e-book readers, mp3 players, etc via USB. Unfortunately I can't use either tool when it comes to most phones and tablets because they show up as devices, not drives. Is there a software that would allow me to setup mappings between folders on my local  PC and on the devices, and push files from PC to device? (I am much less likely to pull data back from the devices to the PC). Command line or UI would be ok.

Comment: That very much depends on your privacy preferences (cloud involved?) and devices to participate (esp. OS) – so it's hard to give a good answer here. You might take a look at [BTSync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_Sync), [git-annex](http://git-annex.branchable.com/assistant/), [Seafile](http://seafile.com/), or [ownCloud](http://owncloud.org/) for privacy-friendly solutions – or check [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) and friends if you prefer working via "somebody else's computer" (aka "the cloud").

Comment: Does it have to be a Windows program, or can it be an Android app that does the syncing? Like the AndFTP app described in [this answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/11844/6834)

Comment: from the point of view of privacy I'd be leaning for something like ownCloud, but since I already use p4 as my server, adding another file storage repository feels like an overkill (plus I get a feeling owncloud has troubles with large files ...)